# How do I apply silicone to an exhaust manifold?

Tags: mercedes-benz, exhaust-manifold, sealant

I’m going to be removing the exhaust manifold as I’m going to be removing the cylinder head. When putting the exhaust manifold back on how exactly do I put the silicone. Currently there is a metal gasket and a sort of silicone sealer. Does the silicone go between the manifold and the gasket or head and gasket or both?

W124 230E 1992 pre facelift

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is year/make/model/engine of the vehicle in question? We could help you much more knowing this information.

Comment: I have never seen any silicone-like product applied to an exhaust manifold.  I doubt that you need anything other than a new gasket.

Comment: It’s a W124 230E 1992 Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2♦

Comment: I've never seen sealant used at the exhaust manifold, either. If there's sealant there, I'd bet it was someone else's attempt to get some bad gaskets to seal. Multi Layer Steel (MLS) gaskets don't require sealant. The *only* sealant which might be able to be used is Permatex Copper, but I don't think it will handle the heat right at the exhaust port.

Comment: Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2♦ Maybe they just did it to make sure it sealed? The same shop was doing the exhaust on a BMW M1 (M1 not 1M) so I thought if someone took an M1 there then they probably know what they’re doing.